# Where are the RadScorpions?

Tags: fallout

In Fallout 1, when you get to Shady Sands, you are tasked with getting rid of some pesky RadScorpions. The only trouble is, if you've put the game down for a while and are just picking it back up, you kind of forget all the details you were told. :)

So where do I go to get rid of those RadScorpions?

Comment: +1 for picking up a game and forgetting the details.  I can't count how many times I've restarted games because of that (Baldur's Gate - I'm looking at you).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get to the radscorpions, you don't use the main/travel map.  Instead talk to Seth (near the gate) and he will take you to the cave entrance.

[Source (for refreshing my memory)](http://www.kaneoheboy.com/fallout/fallshad.html)